# Combining two column conditions in calculated column

Tags: calculated-column

I have a task list which has color coding for Progress Bar and Task Status based on % Complete and Status column values.
I have one more additional condition for:
IF status=Blocked then whatever the % Complete value may be the Progress Bar background color should be Red.

I have following formula for Progress Bar:

```
="<DIV style='display:inline-block;position:relative; width:60px; height:17.5px;border:1px solid;'><DIV style='background-color:"&CHOOSE(INT([% Complete]*10)+1,"red","red","OrangeRed","OrangeRed","DarkOrange","Orange","Gold","yellow","GreenYellow","LawnGreen","Lime")&"; width:"&([% Complete]*100)&"%;'>&nbsp;</DIV><DIV style='position:absolute; top:0px;'>"&TEXT([% Complete],"0%")&"</DIV></DIV>"
```

Task Status:

```
="<span style=""font-weight:bold;color:"&IF(Status="Blocked","red",IF(Status="Completed","limegreen",IF(Status="In Progress","gold",IF(Status="Not Started","lightblue","lightslategray"))))&""">"&Status&"</span>"
```

Tried combining both unsuccessfully:

```
="<DIV style='display:inline-block;position:relative; width:60px; height:17.5px;border:1px solid;'><DIV style='background-color:"&IF(Status="Blocked","red","&CHOOSE(INT([% Complete]*10)+1,"red","red","OrangeRed","OrangeRed","DarkOrange","Orange","Gold","yellow","GreenYellow","LawnGreen","Lime")&"; width:"&([% Complete]*100)&"%;'>&nbsp;</DIV><DIV style='position:absolute; top:0px;'>"&TEXT([% Complete],"0%")&"</DIV></DIV>"
```

Any pointers to solve this issue? 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I ONLY copy/pasted your formula and only added linebreaks and spaces (which SharePoint ignores) in Notepad.

Looking at this:

There is a incorrect double quote at the end of the IF line

The rest seems fine by me.

```
="<DIV style='display:inline-block;position:relative;width:60px;height:17.5px;border:1px solid;'>"
  &"<DIV style='background-color:"
    &IF(Status="Blocked"
      ,"red"
      ,"   HERE IS YOUR TYPO, EITHER ADD A QUOTE OR DELETE THE QUOTE AND THE FOLLOWING &
        &CHOOSE(
          INT([% Complete]*10)+1
              ,"red","red","OrangeRed","OrangeRed","DarkOrange","Orange","Gold","yellow","GreenYellow","LawnGreen","Lime")
    &"; width:"
    &([% Complete]*100)
    &"%;'>&nbsp;</DIV><DIV style='position:absolute; top:0px;'>"
    &TEXT([% Complete],"0%")
  &"</DIV></DIV>"
```

You can also concatenate your 2 existing Calculated Columns to create a new one;
then use that result in your view

Tip: always create complex formulas in Notepad, add linebreaks and spaces to make it readable; SharePoint will ignore them when you paste your formula.

Comment: the changes suggested by you still dont work. "The formula contains a syntax error or is not supported", this is what sharepoint says.

Comment: Alas that error message is about the friendliest you are going to get working with Calculated Columns. Delete all stuff you know is correct, you will eventually find the error. I usually start with the minimal working version and built it step by step. I am not going to do this for you, you will learn from your own mistakes... count the number of double quotes.. should be even... count the number of opening ( and closing )... darn I helped you with this last tip ;-)

Comment: Before people start blaming me for sending you on a wild goose chase and start taking away my StackOverflow points. The problem is with the parameters of the IF statement, you allready saw the problematic "  .. but if you take that away the next parameter CHOOSE starts with a &  . I missed that in my original analysis.. HTH +1

Comment: And don't forget the goose chase .. there is a closing ) for the IF missing..

Comment: Appreciate all the pointers, will update when i am done with this puzzle :)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, built it from scratch and finally it worked. Just tweaked the parameter, i have compared with the Status and added color coding instead of % Complete. But your tips about "()" did help in building this. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am able to achieve the colored background for progress bar based on task status. Used Status column instead of % Complete

```
="<DIV style='display:inline-block;position:relative;width:60px;height:17.5px;border:1px solid;'>"
&"<DIV style='background-color:"
&IF(Status="Blocked","red",
  IF(Status="Completed","limegreen",
  IF(Status="In Progress","gold",
  IF(Status="Deferred","gray",
  ))))
&"; width:"
&([% Complete]*100)
&"%;'>&nbsp;</DIV><DIV style='position:absolute; top:0px;'>"
&TEXT([% Complete],"0%")
&"</DIV></DIV>"
```

.....

Comment: great! If you think my answer was helpfull, you may mark it as an answer. tnx